# Where does windows store old bluetooth pairings? Trying to remove phantom devices

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

This is my send to > bluetooth menu.

[image]

The devices in red no longer exist.  I've ran a powershell script that removes all paired BT devices and they arent listed.  I enabled hidden devices and checked device manager, nothing.  I ran the wonderful device cleanup tool from https://www.uwe-sieber.de/misc_tools_e.html and that did nil.

I can only presume its some kind of cache stored somewhere?  Perhaps in the registry? I'd very much like to do away with those entries if anyone can point me in the right direction!

EDIT: here is an image of my settings > devices.  Unlisted yet still presenting in the transfer menu.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

They won't sit there in the "Send To" menu if you've removed them from "Bluetooth and Other Devices" by going into the settings. Assuming that you are on Windows 10, I have checked and they get removed from the menu if made to do so. Go To

> "Settings">"Bluetooth and other devices"

Now, you will get a list of devices that are paired with your PC, something like this:

[image]

After that, if your pre-removal "Send To" menu looks like this:
[image]

Post-removal, "Send To" menu will be like this:
[image]

That's it. I hope this helps. If not, please update the question and provide more relevant details.